# Decreasing sequence $\{f^{(n)}(0)\}_{n=1}^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for analytic functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f^{(n+1)}(0)<f^{(n)}(0)$ for every integer $n\ge 0$.

I have found an easy family of examples: $f(x)=a^{rx}$, where $0<r\ln a<1$.

Are there more interesting examples? (That is: more examples or more interesing.)

Main question: **Is it possible that $f(0)=0$?**

A result about $\mathcal C^\infty$ functions is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most general example will be obtained by taking any decreasing sequence $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for which the series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{x^n}$ is uniformly convergent on every interval. Then taking $a_0=0$ it is possible of course that $f(0)=0$.